# How to reference same dates between worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

How can I take the date in one worksheet and find the same date in another worksheet column and return the cell reference for that date to use in a loop?

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)

    Dim Lastrow_ws1 As Long
    Lastrow_ws1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim LastDate As Long

 ** Set LastDate = something 'take the last date in ws3 column A and find that date in ws1 column A and find the return the cell reference**

        For y = LastDate To Lastrow
            ws1.Cells(y, "A").Copy
            ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Calculate

'THEN RUN A SEPERATE LOOP USING THE LASTDATE VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

I can help you out, but you'll need to be a bit clearer on the question, and the formatting of your question, you also usually need to be specific as to what your issue is. You can use something like [this](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to get started formatting your code.

Right, so to start of with, you define wb with `Dim wb As Workbook` but you don't set it to anything. I might suggest `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` before you call it with `Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)`

Hard to tell from your code, but `Dim Lastrow_ws1 As Long Lastrow_ws1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` should ideally be across different lines:

```
Dim Lastrow_ws1 As Long
Lastrow_ws1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Now, where you venture into pseudo code: `Set LastDate = something 'take the last date in ws3 column A and find that date in ws1 column A and find the return the cell reference`

You must define `ws3` it's not mentioned anywhere.

In this line `ws1.Cells(y, "A").Copy ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` You mention `ws2`, but it's not defined anywhere.

The loop could be something like:

```
For i in Range("A1","A" & Lastrow_ws1)
If i = LastDate Then
    'Do what you want to do
Else
End If
Next
```

Comment: @Neb967 Great! If you found that my answer fixed your issue, you can accept it as an answer :)